# Can't decrypt property from spring cloud config or environment variable

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-kms

I'm trying to get my KMS library, [found here](https://github.com/hfgbarrigas/gcp-kms-spring-boot), to decrypt items from my application.yml that come from either the google cloud config server or an environment variable.

In playing around I've tried a number of scenarios to get this to work.  Ideally I'd like to be able to do something like:

`username: '{cipher}${db_username}` where `${db_username}` is either a property I read in from google cloud config or an environment variable.

So far what I've tried:

✅`username: ${username}` ->  Successfully reads the plain text property from either the cloud config or environment variable successfully.  (no encryption)

✅`username: '{cipher}MyEncodedString'` ->  Success - decodes the provided inline string

❗️`username: '{cipher}${username}'` -> I believe this is trying to use the literal string `${username}`

❗️`username: '{cipher}'${username}` -> invalid format / can't read

Since I can see that my decode is working when I put the string inline I don't believe this to be an issue with the decoder.

I may also be dumb and this is not a scenario I'd ever want to do, but it seems logical to me that I'd store these in a config area and let the application / profile pull in and decrypt what it needs.

If it makes a difference, and at this point I don't feel it does, I'm attempting to do all of this on Google Cloud Run + Java + Jib

Comment: Can you use the KMS client libraries directly instead of this plugin?

Comment: I don't believe the problem to be the library, just the order in which things are happening in the magical spring boot world.  I need my property to be intjected prior to decryption.  I could look at tooling my own and having it do everything on startup though

Comment: I think the easiest thing to do would be to encrypt the secrets using KMS out of band (do it locally from your laptop) and then store the encrypted values in a properties file. Then, at boot, your application decrypts those values and stores them in-memory.

Comment: doesn't really lead itself to "12-factor" that was as I have to embed a different encrypted file per environment.  It certainly works though

Comment: Aren't you doing that already though with this approach?

Comment: no?...Because I would be deploying the same artifact to each environment but reading the environment / spring cloud config per per environment.  The artifact would stay the same, the variable names it reads would stay the same but the properties would change

Comment: Can you try pre-pending text {cipher} to your encrypted username that you store at google cloud config server or an environment variable and refer it as username: ${username}

Comment: @so-random-dude - that was a great idea and gave me hope - but alas still no luck.  It tried to use the literal string {cipher}abcXYZ as my username/password

Answer (score 0):

can you try to use properties file. properties file doesn't require single quotes for {cipher}. less chances but can work.